# Multiple TinyMCEs breaking Distraction Free Writing

Tags: tinymce

I created a meta box which has multiple tinyMCE editors. However, now when I go to edit a page and click the fullscreen button on the main editor, it shows the content of the metabox.

When I close it and go back to fullscreen, it shows the correct content.

Anyone know where to begin on fixing this? Thanks!

Comment: Showing the code with which you're creating the meta boxes would help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use meta boxes for TinyMCE. It has some kind of conflict with the DOM. Hook your code including `wp_editor` to `edit_page_form` action instead:

```
add_action( 'edit_page_form', 'my_second_editor' );
function my_second_editor() {
    // get and set $content somehow...
    wp_editor( $content, 'mysecondeditor' );
}
```

See [Notes on wp_editor](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor#Notes) in the Codex.